# Mongo DB - how to get a random key from a collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb and I would like to pull a random key and document from a collection so I can have a look at the structure from the shell.  Just for simple exploring.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to look at a single document in the collection, you can simply run

```
db.mycollection.find().limit(1)
```

This will find all documents in the collection `mycollection` but limit the results to 1 document. If you add `.pretty()` to the end, it will format it nicely, rather than just printing everything on one line.

Note that this is not a random document in the sense of a uniform distribution. You may always get the same one.